# text input with other html elements as child, similar to Google+/Facebook's textbox

Tags: html, ajax, facebook, google-plus

I want to create a custom control that have the same behavior as what Google+ and Facebook's textbox have. The one that looks like it have child html elemens.

Please look at the following images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: We cannot code it for you from scratch.

Comment: Tried to create a basic text input with a child div element but the editor says that it is illegal to create a child element under an input element. Just need some guide and I can code it by my self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to position the elements using css. Wrap the input and the other element which you want inside the input inside an element, set its `position:relative;`, then define the element you want inside the input with `position:absolute` and set its `top` and `left` properties to 0 or some other value which fits your purpose.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/eZAU6/

Answer (score 1):

Another answer for the community: If you inspect such "text input" via Google Chrome "Inspect Element" feature, you will see that it's not actually an input element: it is a DIV element with a child (and borderless) input element with same bg color. When the div element gets the focus, it transfers it to the inner (and borderless) input so you can write something. When you pick an element, a new entry is created and inserted in the div BEFORE the inner input element.